# Parse JSON Multiple values into Rows

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

**Requirement**: Parse JSON values into rows

**JSON:**

```
    {
      "uid":"2EDA9DC1D4",
      "m_lg_loc": "ml_0_49_2965_12990434_1450,ml_0_49_2965_12991888_1450,ml_0_49_2965_12997254_682,ml_0_49_2965_12997940_453",
      "codec": "PMMMU,G726-32,PMMMA,A729a,tel",
      "trv_dev": "1,10,2",
        "geoipp": {
        "area_code": 703,
        "location": [
          -77.2223,
          38.94990000014
        ]
      }
    }
```

**Expected Output:**

Need `m_lg_loc` multiple values into rows

```
ml_0_49_2965_12990434_1450
ml_0_49_2965_12991888_1450
ml_0_49_2965_12997254_682
ml_0_49_2965_12997940_453
```

Similarly for

`codec`

```
    PMMMU
    G726-32
    PMMMA
    A729a 
    tel
```

`location`

```
-77.2223
38.94990000014
```

**Tried:**

```sql
select JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT($1, uid) as uid
      ,JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT($1, 'm_lg_loc') as m_lg_loc
 from /path/abc.json (FILE_FORMAT=>JSON_FORMAT)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SPLIT_TO_TABLE to do what you want. Here's an example:

```
create temporary table foo(v variant);

insert into foo select parse_json('    {
      "uid":"2EDA9DC1D4",
      "m_lg_loc": "ml_0_49_2965_12990434_1450,ml_0_49_2965_12991888_1450,ml_0_49_2965_12997254_682,ml_0_49_2965_12997940_453",
      "codec": "PMMMU,G726-32,PMMMA,A729a,tel",
      "trv_dev": "1,10,2",
        "geoipp": {
        "area_code": 703,
        "location": [
          -77.2223,
          38.94990000014
        ]
      }
    }');
    
--Parse the property as a string.
select v:m_lg_loc::string from foo;
--Split to table
select * from foo, table(SPLIT_TO_TABLE(v:m_lg_loc::string, ',')); 
--Get and alias the column(s) you want
select "VALUE" as MY_COLUMN  from foo, table(SPLIT_TO_TABLE(v:m_lg_loc::string, ','));
```

Comment: Thanks, @Greg Pavlik, I see you inserted into a temporary table, Is it possible to get directly from stage s3 path ..Below one got me `SQL compilation error: ambiguous column name '$1'`

```select JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT($1, 'uid') as uid
       ,JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT($1, 'media_leg_locations') as media_leg_locations
       ,$1:media_leg_locations::string
FROM @stage/path
( FILE_FORMAT=>JSON_FORMAT)a
,table(SPLIT_TO_TABLE($1,'media_leg_locations'::string, ','));```

Comment: You have three parameters in your split_to_table function. You'll want to parse the JSON in $1 and assign an alias for it. Almost all the time Snowflake will let you use an aliased column name later in the SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this all in one step using a LATERAL FLATTEN:

```
WITH x AS (
SELECT parse_json('{
      "uid":"2EDA9DC1D4",
      "m_lg_loc": "ml_0_49_2965_12990434_1450,ml_0_49_2965_12991888_1450,ml_0_49_2965_12997254_682,ml_0_49_2965_12997940_453",
      "codec": "PMMMU,G726-32,PMMMA,A729a,tel",
      "trv_dev": "1,10,2",
        "geoipp": {
        "area_code": 703,
        "location": [
          -77.2223,
          38.94990000014
        ]
      }
    }') as js)
SELECT js:uid::varchar, js:m_lg_loc::varchar, y.value::varchar
FROM x,
LATERAL FLATTEN(INPUT => split(x.js:m_lg_loc::varchar,',')) y;
```