# Is there a native snowflake feature for automated refresh of JSON flattening process?

Tags: json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am new to Snowflake and StackOverflow. I hope you all are able to help me!

I have found the documentation and questions on this site that describe how to flatten JSON in snowflake. See documentation links below. However, it doesn't appear to me that these tables can be refreshed in an automated way. It looks like, similar to a Postgres style materialized view, I must manually refresh the data. Is this true, or is there a feature I have not found?

Thanks!
Kate

Documentation references:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/json-basics-tutorial.html
[Flatten nested JSON in snowflake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63920653/flatten-nested-json-in-snowflake)
[Parse JSON Multiple values into Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63194545/parse-json-multiple-values-into-rows)

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake materialized views are automatically maintained and refreshed by Snowflake:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/views-materialized.html#advantages-of-materialized-views